# multiply decimal numbers in PHP

Tags: php

From my database I get a decimal like, 25.30.

In PHP I multiply the decimal like this, 25.30 * 6. The result is 151,8 but with a comma.

The problem is that the result gets me a comma instead of a point like 151.8.

Is there a solution to solve this and get the result with a point?

Comment: `$string = 25.30 * 6;

$string = str_replace(',','.', $string);

print $string;`

Comment: if your getting a comma your regional settings must be set to European standard

Comment: Are you sure? This is what I get http://codepad.org/ecqRO2J9 Show your code.

Comment: [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number-format) ? And THIS ^

Comment: why comma? it should return 151.8 if you are not doing any other operation on answer or changing number format.

Comment: What's your locale setting / PHP version? See this comment: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#25041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to format your number. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

So for example in your case this would be:

```
print number_format($number, 1, '.', ',');
```

Answer (score 2):

try `var_dump(localeconv());`, you'll probably see the `decimal_point` key is `,` so either (if PHP5.3>=) try `locale_set_default('en_US');` or use the (deprecated) `setlocale` function: `setlocale`:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US');
//or custom:
$locale = localeconv();
$locale['decimal_point'] = '.';
$setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
```

More details on the `Locale` class [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php)
On the other apporach [using `setlocale`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and [getting `localeconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php).

A hacky quick-fix might also be:

```
$formatted = sprintf('%.1f',25.30 * 6);
```

But I'd recommend you setting the locales as they should be set. Also note that on windows, `setlocale(LC_ALL)` uses the system locale settings, as stated in the docs:

> On Windows, setlocale(LC_ALL, '') sets the locale names from the system's regional/language settings (accessible via Control Panel).